# On the balanced metric on complex manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $(M,h)$ be a Hermitian manifold and denote the Kahler form of the Hermitian metric by $\omega$. From the definition of Kahler manifold we know that $M$ is a Kahker manifold if $d\omega=0$. A balanced metric is defined as follows:
We say that Hermitian metric $h$ is balanced if $d\omega^{n-1}=0$ where $n$ is the complex dimension of $M$. A proposition is that $d\omega^{n-k}=0$ for any $k>1$ implies that $\omega$ is closed, i.e. $d\omega=0$. So my problem is how to prove it?

Comment: Take $k=n-1$ (if $n >2$).

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean $d\omega ^{n-k}=0$ for *some* $k>1$. This can be written $d\omega \wedge \omega ^{n-k-1}=0$, hence it implies $d\omega \wedge \omega ^{n-3}=0$. Now mutiplication by $\omega ^{n-3}$ induces an  isomorphism of vector bundles $\wedge^3T^*_M\cong \wedge^{2n-3}T^*_M$ (just look on the fiber at each point), hence $d\omega \wedge \omega ^{n-3}$ implies $d\omega =0$.